# Edit menu missing for Views in lightning

Tags: lightning-experience

The "Lightning Experience Guide" doc references on p.58 a "gear menu next to the List view name" which is where I would create and Edit views...  But I do not see that gear (and menu) - My profile is System Admin with Manage Public Views selected.  Any ideas why I am not seeing the gear menu?  - This of course is in my Sandbox. Thanks!